# Unable to access playstore through wifi on any of the android devices connected to it

Tags: android-wifi

I am unable to access Google Play store on my WiFi. I have tried this with a number of android devices and it doesn't work on any of them. However, if I connect them to the data connection, everything works fine. I can browse the web perfectly fine on the phone. Only play store doesn't start. Can anyone give a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Happened exactly like that to me suddenly.  Google Play Store on my phone worked fine with AT&T mobile data but stopped working on Time/Warner wifi.  I went into Android application manager, found Playstore, and tapped the button to uninstall the most recent update of Playstore.  It began working again.  That action also clears the cache & data so that alone may work.

Comment: There was some problem with my router. I connected another router and now everything is fine!